# Accessing information in nested object (JS)

Tags: javascript, loops, object

This is driving me insane. If you don't have a common name for the nested string property, how do you access the information?

example:

```
var fruitStand = {

      'Apples': {
        quantity: 1
      },
      'Pears': {
       quantity: 3
      }
    }
```

I know this:

```
console.log(Object.keys(fruitStand)[0]); // "Apples"
```

How do you get to quantity and 1?

I've tried a variety of options (this, adding all kinds of []s) -I'm sure I'm looking right at it, but can't see it. I also can't seem to find documentation to learn how to access nested objects where the nested object is strings (example: fruitStand.______.quantity //#  -what do you put in the ____ to loop? )

End goal is to iterate through a the object, but I can't get past how to access all the parts, so I haven't tried to loop yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be specific with the duplicate, in your example, it’d be: `var firstKey = Object.keys(fruitStand)[0]; var firstFruit = fruitStand[firstKey]; firstFruit.quantity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:
fruitStand[Object.keys(fruitStand)[0]].quantity

Comment: I can't tell you how long I've been staring at this, such a rookie mistake. Thank you!